# Django: Display message after creating a post

Tags: python-3.x, django

How do i add a simple message after user creates a post e.g "Post has been created"

views.py

```
 class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    
        model = Post
        form_class = PostForm
    
    
        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.author = self.request.user ##author = current logged in user
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

base.html

```
{% if messages %}
  {% for msg in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      {{msg.message}}
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your form_valid and form_invalid methods, you can add the messages.

```
from django.contrib import messages
def form_valid(self, form):
    ....
    msg = 'Your thing has been done successfully'
    messages.add_message(self.request, messages.SUCCESS, msg)
    return super().form_valid(form)
```